# How to rename GraphQL type field autogenerated from Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, graphql, graphene-django

I've a model in Django with some fields. Let's say this exemplary one:

```
# <app>/models.py

from django.db import models


class Something(models.Model):
    first_field = models.Charfield()
    second_field = models.Charfield()
```

I use `DjangoObjectType` from `graphene_django` to map Django models to GraphQL types.

```
# <app>/schema.py

from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Something


class SomethingType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Something
```

Cause of [auto camelcasing](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/schema/#auto-camelcase-field-names) the model field `second_field` results in `secondField` in the GraphQL type. Now I'd like to rename the GraphQL type field from `secondField` to `somethingFancy`. How can I get this done easiest?

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite any field with DjangoObjectType. Your code may look like this.

```
class SomethingType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
       model = Something


   something_fency = graphene.String()

   def resolve_something_fency(self, info):
       return self.second_field
```

For more details check out the [docs](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#customised-fields)